# Creating a Category Taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I have this entertainment site for TV shows. I cover at least 27 shows so far. I use so many different post types for the shows and it slows down the site, I eventually want to add more shows.

I know there has to be a more simple way than creating post types. What I want to do is create a category taxonomy.

Just as wordpress has the category box with a check list, I would like a replica of that box, but instead of saying category I want it to say "TV SHOW" and the link to look like this,

mysite.com/tv-show/show-title/category/post-name

Is that even possible or is there a better way to do this?. Please let me know I'm open to all suggestions.

I don't want to place the shows as categories because I already have categories and I want the shows to be separate from the categories.

Answer (score 1):

I would really suggest using one custom post type and one custom taxonomy with terms under the custom taxonomy which is assigned to a show.

This structure will function exactly like normal posts with normal categories, the only difference is that it will be outside the scope of default blogging as custom post types are excluded from the main query.

There are [methods and plugins](http://www.google.com/search?client=ms-rim&hl=en&q=switch%20custom%20post%20types&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&channel=browser) to change the post type of a post. I would recommend to create one custom post type, then change all the tv shows custom post types to this custom post type and then delete all the other custom post types

You can now [create a taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy) for this custom post type. This will add a metabox to the custom post type post screen which operates the same as that for normal categories. You can go to the custom taxonomy screen and create terms (like categories) which you can assign to a post the same way as you would do it for normal posts and categories

Just one tip, test this locally and play around with it before applying it to a live site, and always create a backup before making changes